# php include - what's wrong with my code?

Tags: php, templates, include, base-url

I am using `*.tpl` files of html and php code to `include` into various webpages on my website to fill in common spaces such as header and footer.

I am trying to include and print the code at the correct place in my website.
I am using the following:

```
<?php
include ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/assets/com-footer.tpl';)
?>
```

I am using a MAMP localhost to run my website and I am puzzled as to how to get this to work? I'm no pro unfortunately!! The initial intention was to get the `baseURL` before the `/assets/com-footer.tpl`
The directory of my tpl files is: `localhost/assets`

I am trying to avoid having to put `../../assets/file.tpl` for some pages. I just want a standard php code that outputs the baseURL of the localhost and the server when it is uploaded to a hosting server. When I have this, I can put it before css stylesheet links and images etc. All to avoid the `../../../` strings I have to add depending on which folder the webpage is saved.

Can anyone shed some light and help me out here?

Comment: Almost. Use `DOCUMENT_ROOT` to make your paths absolute to the webserver base dir. Alternatively use a dispatcher/router script and virtual paths, include pages or templates from there; this allows for a common initialization.

Comment: http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host

Comment: What is the actual error you are receiving? Is it simply that the semi-colon is in the wrong place? It should be after the closing parenthesis.

Comment: @Malcolm: That could possibly be it; just moving the semi-colon. Sad part is new users almost never actually accept the answer that fixes their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
include ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/assets/com-footer.tpl';)
```

To

```
include ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/assets/com-footer.tpl');
```

Comment: MARIO: That works.. but the document_root.. when on a server with httpdocs, would this work? Or is this just a solution for localhost?

Comment: Sorry, Im referring to mario's post of changing HTTP_HOST to DOCUMENT_ROOT.
I am aware of the syntax error. I accidentally typed it wrong in the post.

Comment: try to `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`and see if it displays what u want to concatenate with

Answer (score 0):

If you know your absolute path on the server just set it yourself. I do that sometimes to shorten my PHP code. Create a variable called DOC_ROOT in a php file that is included with all your pages like a config file, header or something. something like so.

```
<?php
    define("DOC_ROOT","/absolute/path/to/httpdocs");
//whatever else after this
?>
```

Then you can just call `include(DOC_ROOT.'/assets/com-footer.tpl');` and use DOC_ROOT anywhere else too.